# Can't point to struct being read from file in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to load some `member` structs I've saved to my `Memberships.txt` binary file. I can read the content into `tmp` without a problem, as the prints give me the correct information. The problem seems to be on the `tail.next = &tmp;` line.

The idea is to keep `head` as a pointer so I can pass it to the other functions I'll use later on. `tail` should initialize with the `member` `head` points to and will only be used to modify the `.next` field on it, so I add the members being read at the end of the list.

Can anyone help me?

```
FILE* f = fopen("Memberships.txt", "rb");
member* head = malloc(sizeof(member));
member tail = *head;
member tmp;
while(fread(&tmp, sizeof(struct member), 1, f) == 1){
  printf("Read member %d from file.\n", tmp.number);
  printf("Name: %s\n", tmp.first_name);
  printf("Surname: %s\n", tmp.second_name);
  tail.next = &tmp;
  tail = tmp;
}
tail.next = NULL;
printf("Loaded %d members into list!\n\n",tail.number);
if(head->next == NULL){
  printf("%d",666);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Read member 1 from file.
Name: Lucas
Surname: Azeve
Read member 2 from file.
Name: Mark
Surname: Lala
Loaded 2 members into list!

666
```

---

I've implemented the changes that @anonmess suggested like:

```
member* head = malloc(sizeof(member));
member tail = *head;
member tmp;
while(fread(&tmp, sizeof(struct member), 1, f) == 1){
    member* read = malloc(sizeof(member));
    strcpy(read->first_name,tmp.first_name);
    strcpy(read->second_name,tmp.second_name);
    strcpy(read->address,tmp.address);
    strcpy(read->email,tmp.email);
    read->number = tmp.number;
    read->annual_fee = tmp.annual_fee;
    read->status = tmp.status;
    read->handicap = tmp.handicap;
    read->bracket = tmp.bracket;
    read->freq = tmp.freq;
    read->rest = tmp.rest;
    read->rate = tmp.rate;
    printf("Read member %s from file.\n", read->first_name);
    printf("Name: %s\n", read->first_name);
    printf("Surname: %s\n", read->second_name);
    tail.next = read;
    tail = *read;
}
```

Obtaining the same results, the problem is on the last two lines. `head->next` is still NULL.

Comment: With a linked list, you need to dynamically allocate the links. So `tmp` should be a pointer, and you `malloc` it at the start of each loop. Right now, you're just overwriting the same memory over and over.

Comment: How can i know how many objects are stored? if not with `fread(&tmp, sizeof(struct member), 1, f) == 1`

Comment: @anonmess if I malloc right below the while, how can i write the info from tmp into the allocated pointer correctly?!

Comment: I suppose you could keep `tmp` as it is, and have another pointer that you `malloc` and add to the list each loop, after copying the data from `tmp`.

Comment: @LucasAzevedo *if I malloc right below the while*  Start by not putting your `fread()` call in the `while()` condition.  Then you can read directly into the newly-`malloc()`'d memory.

Comment: I've edited the question including the most recent modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a stand-alone example you can modify to solve your problem:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define NAME_LENGTH 20

typedef struct _member {
    struct _member *next;
    int number;
    char first_name[NAME_LENGTH];
    char second_name[NAME_LENGTH];
} member;

member member_list[] = {
        { NULL, 1, "Lucas", "Azeve" },
        { NULL, 2, "Mark",  "Lala"  }
};

void create_file(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("Memberships.txt", "wb");
    fwrite(member_list, sizeof(member_list), 1, f);
    fclose(f);
}

int main(void)
{
    create_file();
    FILE* f = fopen("Memberships.txt", "rb");
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("Could not open file");
        exit(errno);
    }
    member *head = malloc(sizeof(member));
    member *tail = head;
    while (1) {
        int result;
        member *new = malloc(sizeof(member));
        result = fread(new, sizeof(*new), 1, f);
        if (1 != result) {
            if (feof(f)) {
                break;
            }
            errno = ferror(f);
            perror("Could not read from file");
            exit(errno);
        }
        printf("Read member %d from file.\n", new->number);
        printf("Name: %s\n", new->first_name);
        printf("Surname: %s\n", new->second_name);
        tail->next = new;
        tail = new;
    }
    fclose(f);
    tail->next = NULL;
    printf("Loaded %d members into list!\n\n", tail->number);
    if (head->next == NULL) {
        printf("%d",666);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Read member 1 from file.
Name: Lucas
Surname: Azeve
Read member 2 from file.
Name: Mark
Surname: Lala
Loaded 2 members into list!
```

Hopefully, this will show you one way to allocate memory for each member and read the data from the file without doing any unnecessary copying. You can safely ignore the code I used to create the file. I needed some data and I always try to get the computer to do as much work as possible.

Comment: thank you very much! i was having issues with the alternative to having the  fread inside the while! spotless code, just forgot the 'int' before errno?

Comment: No, `errno` is supplied by `<errno.h>`. If your compiler is complaining, you forgot to include it.